# How do I fix the issue of "�" instead of åäö?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

On this specific page I got called 'PrintExtraInfo.aspx' every single one of my 'Å Ä Ö' look like this: �.

Nowhere else on the site is this problem.

Any ideas why this would occur?

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="PrintExtraInfo.aspx.cs" Inherits="PrintExtraInfo" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenWin(url, name) {
            window.open(url, name);
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell CssClass="ContactLeftTD">

            <span class="minititle">Först i trafik:</span>
            <div class="divider3">
            </div>
```

Comment: @Vache Unicode is not an encoding. (See http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that caused this problem was that I was inexperienced with FileZilla (working on a live website for the first time instead of a local copy that I've worked on for some weeks now). I had 4 files that I wanted to add (PrintPage.aspx, PrintMoreInfo.aspx...) so I just went into FileZilla and pressed "Add new files", put in the correct file extention and name of the files. Pasted in my code that I had from before and most of it worked. Problem was the encoding as mentioned in the comments in this thread.

What I did to resolve this issue was just to take away those files that I had created in FileZilla and instead uploaded the ones I had created earlier in VS2010 for my local copy of the website which were in the correct encoding and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The encoding of that file is most likely not UTF-8, unlike your other files.

To change it in Visual Studio (at least in VS 2013) go to `File > Advanced Save Options`.

[image: Advanced Save Options]

Comment: VS2013 only has a 30 day free trial. And apparently there's no option like that in VS2010 :/